# What does a red icon mean in TF2 on the killboards?

Tags: team-fortress-2

Sometimes on the killboards, there's an icon like this:

[image]

Normally the background isn't red:

[image]

What does red mean?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the background is red, it means that the weapon killed the player with a crit.

So in your first screenshot, it could be read as:

> `soccer sam88` **Phlogistinator** (*crit*) `killed Table`

whereas the second screenshot would read as:

> `didn't notice you`  **Ubersaw** (*noncrit*) `Neil Armstrong`

As an additional note, as mentioned by users in the comments, the background for mini-crits looks exactly the same as if you had killed the player with the critical hit.

Comment: You misspelled Phlogistinator. Would have corrected it myself, but the change is less than 6 characters in size.

Comment: Red also includes mini-crits.

Comment: too add onto to what @jw013 said, There is a difference between red intensity for crit v. mini-crit, you may want to include screenshots for this.

Comment: @char1es I don't think that's true, but I can't find a definitive answer. The best I can find is that the [wiki](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Kill_icon#Multiple_classes) includes only an icon for critical hits.

Comment: @AustinMohr, I think you may be right. Thanks for the clarification. I heard this somewhere a long time ago and always assumed it to be true I guess.

Comment: Note that most kills (except non-lethal hits with the Holy Mackerel) will be reported in the console, so in this case, the output will be "soccer sam88 killed Table with phlogistinator. (crit)" and "didn't notice you killed Neil Armstrong with ubersaw."